# Solving a first order differential equation involving y and its exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the differential equation
$$y'(x)={2e^{y(x)/x}+\frac{y(x)}{x}}$$
I think it is homogeneous but I have no idea as to how to manipulate this to get it into the required form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $z(x)=\exp(y(x)/x)$ then $y(x)=x\ln(z(x))$ and $y'(x)=\ln(z(x))+\frac{xz'(x)}{z(x)}$. Hence the ODE becomes
$$\ln(z(x))+\frac{xz'(x)}{z(x)}=2z(x)+\ln(z(x)).$$
That is, after separating variables (note that $z(x)>0$),
$$\frac{z'(x)}{z^2(x)}=\frac{2}{x}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Antonio Runcio Sorry there is a typo in my answer (now it is correct). $y'(x)=\ln(z(x))+\frac{xz'(x)}{z(x)}$ . However the procedure for solving it is similar.

Comment: $$\int\frac{z'(x)}{z(x)^2}=2\int\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\frac{-1}{z(x)}=2(\ln(x)+c)$$

$${z(x)}=\frac{-1}{2(\ln(x)+c)}$$
$z(x)=\exp(y(x)/x)$     $$\exp(y(x)/x)=\frac{-1}{2(\ln(x)+c)}$$
$${\frac{y(x)}{x}=\ln(\frac{-1}{2(\ln(x)+c)})}$$
$${{y(x)}=\ln(\frac{-1}{2(\ln(x)+c)})x}$$ It's Ok now?

Comment: @Antonio Runcio Yes, That's the solution for $x>0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Start with the clear $y=x z$ to make the equation $$x z'=2e^z$$ which is separable.